# JSON parsing issue when using filepath as image url

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am having an issue getting my image to upload to the microsoft face api.

I have a function that posts to the server, which implements another function that turns a user selected image into a base64 encoded stream.

```
        public async Task getImageID(){
            //filedialogs, etc...

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            string responseBodyAsText;
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"url\":\""+baseEncodeImage(getPhoto.FileName)+" \"}");

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData)){
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //debug prints
                Console.Write(responseBodyAsText+"\n"+ getPhoto.FileName+"\n"+byteData);
            }
        }

       public string baseEncodeImage(string filePath){
            //This function will take the filepath selected from the filedialog
            //and turn it into a base64 encoded stream to be used by the face api
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    return base64String;
                }
            }


        }
```

It posts to the server, and returns the following in the command line:
[image: Error]

What do I need to manipulate so that it works with the base64 encoding? It was posting with an image url off the internet prior to the modifications.

Comment: I'm not seeing, in this code, where you're actually parsing any JSON. Please [edit] your question to include that, and exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: a) minimise your code to show where the problem is (nobody likes to trawl through somebody else's piles of code). b) As far as I see, you provide local path to the file. How would third party get to your C-drive?

Comment: @trailmax I believe that second part is the issue. If I base64 encode the image, will that mean that the "application/json" becomes an octet stream?

Comment: @AlfredHanson if you mean the request type, then it is still "application/json", including base64 encoded string, not octet.

Comment: @AlfredHanson hold on. There was JSON in your question before editing - is that no longer required to submit to your API?

Comment: @trailmax I still have it, just removed it from the question as I was trying to slim it down. I hope this rewrite is easier for you to understand

Comment: @AlfredHanson I see you've added base64 encoding for the image. Does it still give you the same error?

Comment: @trailmax It gives me the `invalid image` or `invalid url` for octet or json

Comment: @AlfredHanson for `Invalid Image` try this format: `data:image/jpeg;base64,<BASE64E>`, like [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I converted the type returned from the encode function to a `byte[]` and simplified the process by making the `byte[]` the size of the image, and simply writing the binary data to memory. The calling function was further simplified by placing the call in the  using statement and removing the original url formatting which wasnt needed.

```
            // Request body
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            string responseBodyAsText;

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent((baseEncodeImage(getPhoto.FileName))))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //debug prints
                Console.Write(responseBodyAsText + "\n" + getPhoto.FileName + "\n");

            }
        }


        public byte[] baseEncodeImage(string filePath){
            //This function will take the filepath selected from the filedialog
            //and turn it into a base64 encoded stream to be used by the face api
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    FileStream imgStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
                    byte[] blob = new byte[imgStream.Length];
                    imgStream.Read(blob, 0, (int)imgStream.Length);
                    return blob;
                }
            }


        }
```